# Magento attribute option box default value

Tags: jquery, magento

As I found the option box default value in magento here:

`/app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml`

```
<select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
<option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
</select>
```

It shows 'Choose an Option...' as a default value

I try

```
<script>
 $(function() {
 $("#attribute525 option:first-child").attr("selected", true); //color
 $("#attribute272 option:first-child").attr("selected", true); //size
});
</script>
```

to make the default value each attribute set to the first option of each attribute,

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your file

```
app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml
```

Right below

```
var spConfig = new Product.Config(< ?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
```

Paste below JS Code

```
spConfig.setInitialState = function(dropdown_id)
        {
            //select dropdown
            var dropdown = $(dropdown_id);
            //remove empty option from dropdown so it is not selectable after initial selection
            dropdown[0].remove();
            //change selections in dropdowns
            for(index = 0; index < dropdown.length; index++)
            {
                if(dropdown[index].value != "")
                {
                    dropdown.selectedIndex = index;
                    var element = dropdown;
                    var event = 'change';
                    //fire events
                    if(document.createEventObject)
                    {
                        var evt = document.createEventObject();
                        return element.fireEvent('on'+event,evt)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
                        evt.initEvent(event, true, true );
                        return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        <?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
        spConfig.setInitialState("attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>")
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This will make configurable options autoselected on Product view page

Comment: hello, thanks for the answer, but it's still show me 'Choose an Option...' like before, there is another way, that not using hard code? cheers @Slimshadddyyy

Comment: You can see it here http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-make-configurable-options-autoselected-on-configurable-product-view-page/